# Identificar una oración concesiva

Tags: sintaxis

¿Se puede considerar la parte en negrita como una oración concesiva? ¿o es solo una construcción?

> *Él ocupaba la primera parte, que era la más útil y mejor conservada, **aunque también la más pequeña**.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sí, es una oración concesiva, aunque no lo parece porque varios de sus elementos no se dicen explícitamente (el sujeto y el verbo están *elididos*). Pero la puedes expandir así:

> aunque también la más pequeña.
>
> aunque [la primera parte] también [era] la más pequeña.

La palabra **aunque** es un "pegamento" sintáctico que *coordina* dos oraciones y además indica que la segunda oración expresa una dificultad que no impide que la primera se cumpla:

> la primera parte era **la más útil** y la mejor conservada ==> esto es lo que se cumple
>
> aunque
>
> la primera parte era también **la más pequeña**  ==> ésta es la dificultad

Ser *pequeño* es un obstáculo para que un lugar sea *útil*, y en este caso ese obstáculo se sortea, y el lugar sigue siendo útil a pesar de lo pequeño. En eso consiste que una oración sea *concesiva*, y para eso se usan las conjunciones *pese a, a pesar de, aunque y por más que* (y a veces *si bien* y *no obstante*).

El análisis es más complicado, porque en realidad hay una oración principal de la que dependen dos oraciones subordinadas adjetivas que están coordinadas, aunque eso no creo que sea relevante para tu pregunta. Lo pongo por si te resulta útil a continuación:

```
Él | ocupaba la primera parte que era la más pequeña aunque también la más útil
S  |   P
   |
     ocupaba | la primera parte que era la más pequeña aunque también la más útil
      verbo  |    complemento directo
             |
             
          la primera parte    que   era la más pequeña  aunque  también la más útil
          art. adj.    N     pron. |                  |        |                   |
                      sust.   rel. └──────────────────┘  conj. └───────────────────┘
                                    orac. subord. adj.           orac. subord. adj.
```

Comment: Rodrigo, ¡muchísimas gracias x tu respuesta! Es q tengo q analizar oraciones concesivas y hay frases cm x ejemplo: „En su casa lo hizo todas las noches antes de dormir, y desde entonces adquirió el hábito de fumar, aunque siempre a escondidas.“ ¿Crees q debería considerar estas construcciones cm ORACIONES? (ya q el verbo no está expresado explícitamente pero las oraciones pueden ser expandidas)

Comment: Son oraciones. Si el verbo es el mismo no se repite, por economía, a menos que esté muy lejos y se pierda la referencia. En este caso "aunque siempre [lo hizo] a escondidas", el verbo "hacer" se subentiende y por eso se omite. Lo mismo pasa con el sujeto.